# how to change color code in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Hi guys i try to enter a color code number in place from the color word `$("#Tcounter").css("color","black")`; in this script from `"black"` to `"#317D29"`. How can I do this?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()  {
    var Tcharacters = <?php echo $max_character_length_title; ?>;
    $("#Tcounter").append("<small><?php osc_esc_js(_e('You have','ctg_housing')); ?> <strong>"+  Tcharacters+"</strong> <?php osc_esc_js(_e('characters remaining','ctg_housing')); ?></small>");
    $("#title<?php echo osc_current_user_locale(); ?>").keyup(function(){
    if($(this).val().length > Tcharacters){
        $(this).val($(this).val().substr(0, Tcharacters));
        }
    var Tremaining = Tcharacters -  $(this).val().length;
    $("#Tcounter").html("<small><?php osc_esc_js(_e('You have','ctg_housing')); ?> <strong>"+  Tremaining+"</strong> <?php osc_esc_js(_e('characters remaining','ctg_housing')); ?></small>");
    if(Tremaining <= 10)
    {
        $("#Tcounter").css("color","red");
    }
    else
    {
        $("#Tcounter").css("color","black");
    }
});
</script>
```

Thanks

Comment: And… what's the problem there? Just type `#317D29` instead of `black`.

Comment: @Ansel Mae Why is `$("#Tcounter").css("color","#317D29")` not working?

Comment: No that is not working

Comment: but it works when it is just black?

Comment: Your script above is not even valid

Comment: @epascarello I guess it's black by default and there's something wrong with the rest of the code, so `.css()` never executes…

Comment: Yes in black it works and when 10 characters left it get red

Comment: If you open the resulting script in the debug window, are all php code replaced correctly by their values? Is Tcharacters always an integer? Else should you parseInt() it before subtracting. HAve you found the line number that throws the error? Since you include php, we can't really test your code, sicne we don't know what the php will change into.

Comment: Please add your **HTML** code maybe the problem is there !

Answer (score 0):

first let me know Tcounter is id or class.

if Tcounter is class use:  `$(".Tcounter").css("color","#ff0000");`

if Tcounter  is id then use: `$("#Tcounter").css("color","#ff0000");`

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
                $(".Tcounter").css("color","#ff0000");
        $("#Tcounter").css("color","#ADFF2F");
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p class="Tcounter">Red Color using class</p>
<p id="Tcounter" >Green Color using Id</p>
<button >Set background-color of p</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_colors.asp refer this for css color codes use the same. if must add jquery script, please check that one also. <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use hex code, do this.

$("#Tcounter").css("color","#317D29");

Comment: This script will work as expected. Make sure your script is valid before down voting the answers.

Comment: i find the mistake the color is a default inside the css file

Comment: Yes its working now the problem was the body color in the css file